# c++17 Aggregate Initializations

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2017, aggregate-initialization

I am watching a video series on youtube by Jason Tuner and on this particular video found here: [Aggregate Initializations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMqWoT016cA&list=PLs3KjaCtOwSZ2tbuV1hx8Xz-rFZTan2J1&index=26) he starts off using clang++ c++03 and then changes compiler to clang++ c++11 then when he incorporates the base class hierarchy he changes it to using c++17 or c++1z using a recent build of clang++.

I have just recently downloaded and installed MSVS2017RC and I'm running Windows 7 64bit SP1 on an Intel Quad Core Extreme.

However when I try to follow his video while having this in my IDE

```
struct B {
    double q;
};

struct S : B {
    int i;
    float f;
};

int main() {
    S s{ {}, 1, 2.3f };
    return s.f;
}
```

I am getting this compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test1z, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>Test1z.cpp
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\test1z\test1z\test1z.cpp(15): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'S'
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\test1z\test1z\test1z.cpp(15): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\test1z\test1z\test1z.cpp(16): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>Done building project "Test1z.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does Visual Studio 2017 have the support of these features that are found in c++17? If so are there special compiler options that need to be set in the project properties? Or is this currently exclusive to clang or gcc? What is the main reason for MS's compiler error `C2440` if this is supposed to be a c++17 compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 [does not support all, or most, of C++17](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/11/c1417-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-15-preview-5/) at the present time. Among the things it does not support is aggregate initialization of base classes.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification. I did see on MSDN page that it does say that aggregate is okay but not with a base class or inheritance yet cppreference website does show similar syntax support as found in the video series mentioned above.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: The Cppreference page does not say that VS2017 will do that. In fact, it says quite the opposite. Under "Aggregate initialization of classes with base classes", Visual Studio has a big, red space.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me; I didn't mean to explicitly say that cppreference is stating that it is supported by VS2017; I was just stating that it is valid syntax for c++17. Also after looking at the list in the link that you provided; it appears that MS is starting to fall behind the curve.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: Starting? VS has been behind the curve on C++ features since 2011. VS2010 may have had a couple of C++11 features, but pretty much every other compiler had more C++11 features by the time C++11 actually shipped. Even 6 years after 2011, VS still doesn't fully implement C++11.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to notice that now. I've primarily been using Windows since version 3.11 {...} back when I was in middle school, however, the one nice thing about VS is their IDE. It's just a shame that MS didn't implement everything in the standards or upcoming standards as well as even maybe having their own "experimental" that is above and beyond the standard and different than what the open source communities or other proprietary software such as Intel's, IBM or Apple(MAC) are doing. ...

Comment: ... Since I've always enjoyed computer games especially those with 3D Graphics and that I excel both in math and the sciences, I have gained the passion to learn on my own what it takes to build a 3D Game Engine from Scratch. Since most games from the 80s to present were focused towards Windows which primarily uses DirectX; I learned it through web text formats for both C# & C++. I finally found an excellent website that went through the process of building a 3D Game Engine except it used OpenGL that was more towards academia, scientific and research 3D modeling. ...

Comment: ...It's brought me to where I am now in. I have learned a lot over the past 10 years independently with no formal training or education with degree and I've learned many: concepts, topics, algorithms, do's and don'ts, pitfalls, and gotchas that it has helped me into trying to master the C++ language. Yet as much as you can learn and as much as there is out there even if one studied it their whole life they would only scratch the surface of it along with its potential due to the ever changing and evolving compilers. Hmm; pun intended: Relearning a Standard? ...

Comment: ... Joke included; I thought a standard is something that is supposed to be fixed, permanent and never changing... Shouldn't it be possible to all agree with a single thing and just stick with it; otherwise it should invite confusion. I do apologize for the succession of comments and the sort of misuse or abuse of it; but I had to express a little bit bout myself here such as a public journal entry for my thoughts are wandering for a family member and a loved one was admitted to the hospital early this morning and it has been an extremely long day. I hope yours was a brighter one.